# The correct xsl for given xml?

Tags: xml, xslt

My xml is

```
     <?xml version='1.0'?>
     <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="country.xsl"?>
     <countries>
       <country name="india">
           <name>Rajan</name>
           <pop>90.09</pop>
           <car>Audi</car>
       </country>
       <country name="japan">
          <name>Yenhovong</name>
          <pop>172</pop>
          <car>Sumo</car>
       </country>
      </countries>
```

Here i want display the elements of

> country name="japan"

using xslt. But I dont know match the attribute in xslt. Help me, thanks in advance

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a solution that employs the most fundamental XSLT design pattern -- the use and overriding of the identity rule. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Xpath expression for it will be `country[@name = 'japan']`.

**XML**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="country.xsl"?>
<countries>
    <country name="india">
        <name>Rajan</name>
        <pop>90.09</pop>
        <car>Audi</car>
    </country>
    <country name="japan">
        <name>Yenhovong</name>
        <pop>172</pop>
        <car>Sumo</car>
    </country>
</countries>
```

**XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="country[@name = 'japan']">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="country"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**RESULT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<country name="japan">
    <name>Yenhovong</name>
    <pop>172</pop>
    <car>Sumo</car>
</country>
```

Comment: It produce the result both 'japan' and 'india' values. Why?

Comment: I have one doubt, The apply-tempates tag does not produce the sequential. It produce only as per the sequence of xml. Why?

Comment: @Venkatesh which `apply-templates`?

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(ancestor-or-self::country)]">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="country[not(@name='japan')]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<countries>
    <country name="india">
        <name>Rajan</name>
        <pop>90.09</pop>
        <car>Audi</car>
    </country>
    <country name="japan">
        <name>Yenhovong</name>
        <pop>172</pop>
        <car>Sumo</car>
    </country>
</countries>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<country name="japan">
   <name>Yenhovong</name>
   <pop>172</pop>
   <car>Sumo</car>
</country>
```

**Do note**:

1. The identity rule is used to copy every wanted node "as-is". The use and overriding of the identity template is the most fundamental XSLT design pattern.
2. A single template overrides the identity rule for any element that has a `country` ancestor or isn't itself a `country` element. Such elements are not copied to the output, but their children-nodes are processed.
3. An overriding template matching any `country` element whose `name` attribute is not `'japan'`. This has empty body and this results in any such elements ignored/deleted/not-copied.
4. The result of 1 to 3 above is that only a `country` element whose `name` attribute is `'japan'` is processed by the identity template and is copied to the output.